# "My Cart" not redirecting to checkout cart

Tags: cart, error, redirect

I have been configuring my store for a few days now and everything was going smoothly but for some reason now the default shopping cart button (My Cart) does not actually redirect to the shopping cart (/checkout/cart/), it simply just redirects to “#”. Ie, the actual html behind the button looks like:

```
<a id="cartHeader" href="#"><span class="title-cart">My Cart</span><strong class="amount">(1</strong>)</a>
```

I don’t know if it was a setting I changed but I wouldn’t think this would be an issue. Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Are you using custom theme ? normal code for add to cart button have onclick event with code like : onclick="setLocation('http://localhost/magento/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9tYWdlbnRvL2luZGV4LnBocC9sYXB0b3BzLmh0bWw,/product/7/')"

Comment: Yeah it's a custom theme, but I was sure it was working before and I haven't changed anything.

Comment: Check your theme file with basic file for code comparison.I think theme is not fully completed for magento code.

Answer (score 2):

According to your code, there is no event attached to it.
Look in below mentioned file for default magento code for add to cart button

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Comment: I'll have a look in that file and see if I can spot any issues.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your link doesn't call the cart

> 

the href="#" will allow you to click but will not go anywhere.

You should be using:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
```